# Apache2 server run script as specific user

Tags: php, python, apache

I am using Ubuntu server 12.04 to run Apache2 web server.

I am hosting several webpages, and most are working fine.

One page is running a cgi script which mostly works (I have the python code working outside Apache building the html code nicely.)

However, I am calling a home automation program (heyu) and it is returning different answers then when I run it in my user account.

Is there a way I can...

1 call the heyu program from my python script as a specific user, (me) and leave the rest of the python code and cgi code alone?

2, configure apache2 to run the cgi code, as a whole, as me? I would like to leave all the other pages unchanged. Maybe using the sites_available part.

3, at least determine which user is running the cgi code so maybe I can get heyu to be OK with that user.

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: For #3, you should be able to use ``from getpass import getuser``

Comment: Thanks shadow that worked. I was able to determine my script is using user www-data. Now to work toward running the call from my script to heyu using me.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then. Feel free to mark it as correct if you feel it assisted you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I could use suEXEC.

It is an Apache module that is not installed at default because they really don't want you to use it. It can be installed using the apt-get scheme.

That said, I found the real answer to my issue, heyu uses the serial ports to do it's work. I needed to add www-data to the dialout group then reboot.

This circumvented the need to run my code as me (as I had already add me to the dialout group a long time ago) in favor of properly changing the permissions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are using python, you can use the following to extract the user that the python script as running as;

```
from getpass import getuser
print getuser()
```

When you hit the page, you'll get the username that the script ran as - and you can from there adjust the permissions of that specific user accordingly.